# getElementsByClassName in context of vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In the context of vue.js, how does getElementsByClassName work?

I have the following snippet of code below - the goal is to click a button and change the color of the h1 tag to green using vue.js methods:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1 class="main-header">{{ message }}</h1>
        <button v-on:click="colorChange">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue!'
            },
            methods: {
                colorChange: function() {
                    // what do I do here...?
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's to my understanding that Vue is like React with a virtual DOM and you don't modify it directly.

Obviously in vanilla JS you just do `document.getElementsByClassName('main-header')[0].style.backgroundColor="green";` but that seems counterintuitive in Vue.

Am I overcomplicating this and is this in fact how it works? Or does Vue have a specific way of handling this? I've been looking at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html but it just explains how to bind classes. I'm also reading through https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html but I'm having a hard time finding what I need in regards to targeting an element/modifying it in some way...

How do you select and/or modify an element in the context of Vue?

Comment: you can always use refs if you're looking into interact with elements inside your component [vue refs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref),

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct.  In Vue, interacting directly with the DOM is counter-intuitive.

Fortunately, there is a directive that allows you to apply style changes directly by binding to a data property.  (Keep in mind, you could do something similar with a class as well).

```
<h1 class="main-header" v-bind:style="{ color: activeColor}">{{ message }}</h1>
<button v-on:click="colorChange">Click me</button>
```

In your component, create a data property and update it on button click:

```
data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    activeColor: 'red'
},
methods: {
    colorChange: function() {
        this.activeColor = 'green'
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified - how would I target the h1?

Comment: What do you mean target it?  Vue will handle the "targeting" based on the v-bind:style that is applied to the h1 element.  In a component-based library, you shouldn't need to worry about targeting the element directly since the positioning of your attributes will tell the framework how to handle the element on your behalf.

Comment: I'm used to jQuery type stuff so `$(".main-header").css('background-color', 'green');` and am trying to break away from that and do Vue style work and so thats what I meant by "targeting" but this makes sense.

Comment: Completely understandable and you have it exactly right, it is a definite break from what you are used to.  In Vue/React/Angular etc, there's a fundamental mindset shift from manually applying style changes to the DOM and letting the framework "react" to data changes and update the DOM on your behalf.