# Toggle between two colors vueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is a follow up on my previous question from today here: [getElementsByClassName in context of vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53176101/getelementsbyclassname-in-context-of-vue)

I now want to modify the code so that every time I click it toggles between the two colors.

My first attempt at that is this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <style>
            .main-header {
                color: #292c2e;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1 class="main-header" v-bind:style="{color: clickedColor}">{{ message }}</h1>
        <button v-on:click="colorChange">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue!',
                clickedColor: '',
                alteredState: false
            },
            methods: {
                colorChange: function() {
                    console.log(this.alteredState);
                    this.alteredState = true;
                    if (this.alteredState == true) {
                        this.clickedColor = 'green'
                        this.alteredState = false;
                    } else {
                        this.clickedColor = ''
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically my thought process here...what I'm doing (trying) here is that I have a second dataset called `alteredState` - I initially have that set to false. In the change color function, I then set it to true. After I set it to true, I check if its true. If so, change the color and revert it back to false. My expectation is that on the second click, it reverts back to the main color and then on the second click it goes back to green.

What ends up happening is that it changes to green, then it's indefinitely set to false and doesn't go back to black.

How come that didn't work?

I then learned out about props https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html and tried something like this (which seems like a step in the right direction):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <style>
            .main-header {
                color: #292c2e;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1 class="main-header" v-bind:style="{color: clickedColor}">{{ message }}</h1>
        <button v-on:click="colorChange">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue!',
                clickedColor: ''
            },
            state: {
                alteredState: 'false'
            },
            methods: {
                colorChange: function() {
                    this.clickedColor = 'green'
                    this.alteredState.setState = 'true'
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I don't understand how to change the value of the state, as the Vue docs don't really explain it.

To toggle between two different colors for a header when a button is clicked is State the best way? Or was I closer with attempt #1 with the ifs etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `this.alteredState = true;` before condition block, and toggle between black and green by clicking on the button which changes also the `alteredState` value :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <style>
            .main-header {
                color: #292c2e;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1 class="main-header" v-bind:style="{color: clickedColor}">{{ message }}</h1>
        <button v-on:click="colorChange">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue!',
                clickedColor: '',
                alteredState: false
            },
            methods: {
                colorChange: function() {
                    console.log(this.alteredState);
                 
                    if (this.alteredState ) {
                        this.clickedColor = 'green'
                        this.alteredState = false;
                    } else {
                        this.clickedColor = '#000'
                         this.alteredState = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `alteredState` to true, and then immediately check to see if it's true -- so it's always true.

There's no reason for your `alteredState` variable at all; you can just toggle based on the current color:

```
colorChange: function() {
  if (this.clickedColor == 'green') {
    this.clickedColor = '';
  } else {
    this.clickedColor = 'green'
  }
}
```

But if you really wanted that `alteredState` var, you'd want to set it based on the toggle state, not set it true every time:

```
    colorChange: function() {
      if (this.alteredState) {
        this.clickedColor = 'green'
        this.alteredState = false;
      } else {
        this.clickedColor = ''
        this.alteredState = true;
      }
    }
```

Also be mindful of the difference between `true` (the boolean) and `'true'` (the string).

Answer (score 0):

I think **@Boussadjra Brahim**'s answer is kinda' OK, but I'd clean it up a bit, and eliminate the initial double-click-to-change-color problem.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    clickedColor: 'red', // set the initial value; I used red, so you can see the different states
    alteredState: true
  },
  methods: {
    colorChange: function() {
      console.log(this.alteredState);

      if (this.alteredState) {
        this.clickedColor = 'green'
      } else {
        this.clickedColor = '#000'
      }
      // this is toggle function, so it's OK to
      // toggle the state every time the button is clicked
      this.alteredState = !this.alteredState
    }
  }
})
```

```css
/* you don't need this CSS, as you set the color with :style */


/*.main-header {
    color: #292c2e;
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1 class="main-header" :style="{color: clickedColor}">{{ message }}</h1>
  <button v-on:click="colorChange">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Hope this helped you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is late but will help other peoples to implement a perfect toggle button.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  props: {
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    labelEnableText: {
      type: String,
      default: 'On'
    },
    labelDisableText: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Off'
    },
    id: {
      type: String,
      default: 'primary'
    },
    defaultState: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentState: this.defaultState
    }
  },

  computed: {
    enableText() {
      return this.labelEnableText;
    },

    disableText() {
      return this.labelDisableText;
    },

    isActive() {
      return this.currentState;
    },

    checkedValue: {
      get() {
        return this.currentState
      },
      set(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
        this.currentState = newValue;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.toggle__button {
    vertical-align: middle;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle__button input[type="checkbox"] {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
}
.toggle__button .toggle__switch {
    display:inline-block;
    height:12px;
    border-radius:6px;
    width:40px;
    background: #BFCBD9;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #BFCBD9;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: all .25s;
}

.toggle__button .toggle__switch::after, 
.toggle__button .toggle__switch::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: -3px;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: all .25s cubic-bezier(.5, -.6, .5, 1.6);
}

.toggle__button .toggle__switch::after {
    background: #4D4D4D;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #666;
}
.toggle__button .toggle__switch::before {
    background: #4D4D4D;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    opacity:0;
}

.active .toggle__switch {
    background: #adedcb;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #adedcb;
}

.active .toggle__switch::after,
.active .toggle__switch::before{
    transform:translateX(40px - 18px);
}

.active .toggle__switch::after {
    left: 23px;
    background: #53B883;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #53B883;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p><strong>Basic Example</strong></p>
  <label :for="id + '_button'" :class="{'active': isActive}" class="toggle__button">
    <span v-if="isActive" class="toggle__label" v-text="enableText"></span>
    <span v-if="! isActive" class="toggle__label" v-text="disableText"></span>

    <input type="checkbox" :disabled="disabled" :id="id + '_button'" v-model="checkedValue">
    <span class="toggle__switch"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Take a look for more details https://webomnizz.com/create-toggle-switch-button-with-vue-js/